# Calling Html Helper Method from Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, razor, jqgrid, html-helper

I am trying to call a custom Html helper method that I have written from a javascript function that is used by jqGrid to return formatted text, in this case a link, for a cell:

```
function formatGroupPlanEditLink(cellValue, options, rowObject) {
        //var cellHtml = "<a href='/Insurance/GroupPlanEdit/?id=" + rowObject[0] + "'>" + rowObject[1] + "</a>";
    var functionArgs = rowObject[1] + ',Url.Action("GroupPlan", "Insurance", new { id = ' + rowObject[0] + ' }),String.Format("Edit {0}", ' + rowObject[1] + '), listId,Url.Action("GroupPlanList", "Insurance"),false';
    var cellHtml = '@Html.DialogFormLink(' + functionArgs + ')';
    return cellHtml;
}
```

The problem that I have is that I cannot concatenate the entire string before the helper is executed.  So the browser is trying to execute "@Html.DialogFormLink(" - which of course causes an error.  I guess there must be a better way to go about this.  I really want to still be able to use the Html helper method as I use it elsewhere, and it works nicely for my requirements.

Comment: If an "HTML Helper" is something to do with Razor, the problem is that what you're trying to do makes no sense. The Razor stuff happens on the server, but your JavaScript runs *after* the page has been sent to the client browser.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Razor, but the quotes around the @Html helper look suspicious.

var cellHtml = **'@Html.DialogFormLink('** + functionArgs + ')';

The browser doesn't execute @Html.DialogFormLink; the server evaluates it.   I suspect the server is injecting the literal '@Html.DialogFormLink' into your js.